# Missing endtime whie inserting to calendar event

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

while trying to insert and event i continously getting the same error although i try to use different time zone and even copy pasted the the code snippet provided [Events:insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert).
The error i am getting is :
`<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Missing end time.". Details: "Missing end time.">`

The code i am using to create the event is :

```
    event = {
        'summary': data['summary'],
        'description': data['description'],
        'start': {
            'dateTime': data['start_time'],
            'timeZone': 'ASIA/KOLKATA',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': data['end_time'],
            'timeZone': 'ASIA/KOLKATA',
        },
        'recurrence': [
            'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
        ],
        'attendees': [
            {'email': 'moinkhan8439@gmail.com'},
            {'email': 'zainkhanjune@gmail.com'},
            ],
        'reminders': {
            'useDefault': False,
            'overrides': [
            {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
            {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
            ],
        }
    }
created_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
```

I tried converting to RFC3339 but same error .
Note - i am getting data from a POST request through a serializer.

Answer (score 1):

This error occur when we dont pass the correct format in the body section of the insert fucntion.

`service.events().insert(calendarId='primary',sendNotifications=True, body=event).execute()`

I found out that i was passing the datetime object into datetime keyword for event whereas we have to **first convert the datetime into standard RFC339** as specififed under authorization section  [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)
and then convert it to string to be passed into event body.

To convert Django models.datetime object into RFC3339 string do this:

`str(date.isoformat('T'))`